# Remove Gmail contacts from iPhone contacts list

Tags: contacts, gmail, iphone

My iPhone has pulled in all contacts from my Gmail account into my contact list. It’s gotten so out of hand that it’s difficult to find contacts I need.

Is there any easy way to remove these and keep them from coming in again?

iPhone 6, iOS 10.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → Contacts → Accounts → *your Gmail account* and turn off Contacts.
Choose ‘Delete from iPhone’ to remove them from your iPhone contacts list.

Comment: I don’t see my gmail account listed there. It only says iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply "hide" them from the contact list by tapping on the "groups" link/button at the top left of the contacts screen (scroll down until the GOOGLE MAIL appears and uncheck the lines about the contact subgroups - or ALL - that you want to hide)

if you really want to delete those contacts from the iPhone, go to Settings → Account & Password → Google Mail
and disable the Contact section

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings in your Iphone -> Contacts (App) -> Accounts -> Select the Gmail account shown and choose Remove account.

This will completely remove the copy of contacts on iphone that are imported from Gmail.

Comment: OP already said “I don’t see my gmail account listed there.”